# Add dynamic reference/threshold line to each bar in bar / hbar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add reference line to each bar in barplot. I see tons of similar question but they using single hlines / vlines to create line across the bar.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"label":["A","B","C"],"value":[10,15,20],"limit":[15,20,15]})
plt.barh(df["label"],df["value"])
# How to add multiple reference line???
```

The output I'm expecting is like this(red lines are the limit) :
[image]

Comment: loop though `df` and plot a vline for each `df[limit]` value.

Comment: I'm kinda suspect things like that. with this code : 
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    plt.vlines(row['limit'],ymin=0,ymax=2)

i'm confused with ymin and ymax in this categorical setting.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation of plt.bar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), it seems that the width of one bar is 0.8 per default, so I guess to plot a line over the bottom bar you need ymin=0.1 ymax=0.9. Then you can use +i to increase by one for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from the comments, here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"label":["A","B","C"],"value":[10,15,20],"limit":[15,20,15]})
plt.barh(df["label"],df["value"])

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    plt.vlines(row['limit'],ymin=idx-0.5,ymax=idx+0.5,colors="red")
```

Comment: The default height is 0.8, so I can use 0.4 to match the height.